# Filter list within list to get all second numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to filter the following list:

```
filtered = [[1.0, 3.0], [2.0, 70.0], [40.0, 3.0], [5.0, 50.0], [6.0, 5.0], [7.0, 21.0]]
```

To get every second number in the list within list, resulting in the following:

```
filtered = [[3.0], [70.0], [3.0], [50.0], [5.0], [21.0]]
```

I tried the following which does not work:

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = map(itemgetter(0), filtered)
print(a)
```

The following also doesn't work:

```
from operator import itemgetter
b = map(filtered,key=itemgetter(1))[1]
print(b)
```

In the last line of code i have shown, if I change map to max, it does find the largest value of all the second floats in the lists. So i assume that i am close to a solution?

Comment: `[[i[1]] for i in filtered]`?

Comment: @sacul i need each second float, thus like this [[1[i]] from filtered. Or is that a line of code I can use?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you actually want a bunch of single element element lists?

Comment: The reasons the first one doesn't work are (a) you're using `itemgetter(0)` when you want to get item 1, not item 0, and (b) you're printing out the map object. Otherwise, it's fine. For example, if you do `a = map(itemgetter(1), filtered)` and then `print(*a)` you'll see `3.0 70.0 3.0 50.0 5.0 21.0`. Or, if you do `a = list(map(itemgetter(1), filtered))`, you'll get the list `[3.0, 70.0, 3.0, 50.0, 5.0, 21.0]`. A list comprehension would probably be nicer for that case than `map`, but `map` does work.

Comment: Of course if you actually want single-element lists, it doesn't do that, but you can adapt any of the variants. Although in that case it's even more obviously nicer with a list comprehension—`itemgetter(slice(1, None))` is pretty ugly compared to `i[1:]` (or `[i[1]]`).

Comment: @sacul Now i understand your reply. List comprehension indeed works for me.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for your reply. I used the list comprehension method which seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
x = [[el[1]] for el in filtered]
```

or:

```
x = [[y] for x,y in filtered]
```

You can also use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). To print it, iterate over the [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) object returned by [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). You can use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) for instance.

```
from operator import itemgetter
x = map(itemgetter(1), filtered)
print(list(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closer to a solution trying to pass a `key` to `map`. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) only takes a function and an iterable (or multiple iterables). Key functions are for ordering-related functions (`sorted`, `max`, etc.)

But you were actually pretty close to a solution in the start:

```
a = map(itemgetter(0), filtered)
```

The first problem is that you want the second item (item 1), but you're passing 0 instead of 1 to `itemgetter`. That obviously won't work.

The second problem is that `a` is a `map` object—a lazily iterable. It does in fact have the information you want:

```
>>> a = map(itemgetter(1), filtered)
>>> for val in a: print(val, sep=' ')
3.0 70.0 3.0 50.0 5.0 21.0
```

… but not as a list. If you want a list, you have to call `list` on it:

```
>>> a = list(map(itemgetter(1), filtered))
>>> print(a)
[3.0, 70.0, 3.0, 50.0, 5.0, 21.0]
```

Finally, you wanted a list of single-element lists, not a list of elements. In other words, you want the equivalent of `item[1:]` or `[item[1]]`, not just `item[1]`. You can do that with `itemgetter`, but it's a pretty ugly, because you can't use slice syntax like `[1:]` directly, you have to manually construct the slice object:

```
>>> a = list(map(itemgetter(slice(1, None)), filtered))
>>> print(a)
[[3.0], [70.0], [3.0], [50.0], [5.0], [21.0]]
```

You could write this a lot more nicely by using a `lambda` function:

```
>>> a = list(map(lambda item: item[1:], filtered))
>>> print(a)
[[3.0], [70.0], [3.0], [50.0], [5.0], [21.0]]
```

But at this point, it's worth taking a step back: `map` does the same thing as a generator expression, but `map` takes a function, while a genexpr takes an expression. We already know exactly what expression we want here; the hard part was turning it into a function:

```
>>> a = list(item[1:] for item in filtered)
>>> print(a)
```

Plus, you don't need that extra step to turn it into a list with a genexpr; just swap the parentheses with brackets and you've got a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [item[1:] for item in filtered]
>>> print(a)
```